# HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type Visual Studio performance testingA ( Content Type)

Tags: visual-studio, automation, performance-testing, content-type, request-headers

I am doing performance testing using visual studio, Here when i post data in certain API it gives me Unsupported Media Type error, For this i used Fiddler
i copied all the headers from Request Headers but its still showing me the same issue 
As in Response I donot see Content  Type 
Below are the Request Header from Fiddler following to it is Response headers from fiddler:

https://www.screencast.com/t/jJoPxxoBloH3

This is the Request shown on Visual Studio :
https://www.screencast.com/t/zRGeWZPUnj6s

And this is the response i got :

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Pragma : no-cache
Content-Length : 0
Cache-Control : no-cache
Date : Fri, 06 Apr 2018 08:46:09 GMT
Expires : -1
Server : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By : ASP.NET
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show (as text) the headers that Fiddler detects and also the headers that Visual Studio sends (from the "Request" tab of the results area). You could also use Fiddler to record what happens when Visual Studio runs the test and include the headers that that shows.

Comment: Including links to pictures on external web site is not how this site works. See [discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)